# In Drupal 7, how can I include a CSS file only when the front page is being viewed?

Tags: 7, theming

I'd like to include a particular CSS file only when the front page is being viewed, since it only applies to the front page, and it's a relatively large file. I know that the solution will involve using [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7), but I'm not sure where in my theme's `template.php` file this would go. Is there a particular hook within my theme that I should be implementing to use this? Thanks.

EDIT: I essentially have the code down, I'm just not sure what hook is available to my theme files to implement. The actual code will look something like...

```
if (!strlen(request_path())) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme'). '/css/front.css');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page (&$variables)
{
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme'). '/css/front.css');
  } 
}
```

See [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) and [drupal_is_front_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module allows you to do just that.

Comment: While this would work, and I certainly appreciate the suggestion, this should be like 5 lines of code in a theme. The only unknown is what hook to use in my `template.php` file. I'd rather not go the route of enabling a full module for a small, single circumstance if I can avoid it.

Comment: I agree, I use the same "keep it simple" approach ;-)